# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when using Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, syntax-error

I am just getting started using firebase and I keep getting an error. It says it is on line thirty one. Thanks in advance! I am a beginner to firebase. I am interediate at javascript. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <title>firebase</title>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
   <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
 // Your web app's Firebase configuration
 var firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
   appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   measurementId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 };
 rules_version = '2';
// Grants a user access to a node matching their user ID
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
   // Files look like: "user/<UID>/path/to/file.txt"
   match /user/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
     allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;

   }
 }
}
</script>
<script>
 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
 // Handle Errors here.
 var errorCode = error.code;
 var errorMessage = error.message;
 // ...
});
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `service firebase.storage {` would not be valid JavaScript. This would need to live in a file such as `firebase.storage` that is mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start) and deployed/uploaded when you make changes via `firebase-tools` or updated in the dashboard.

Comment: You're supposed to have the rules `service firebase.storage` inside your Firebase console, not in the webpage.